# How to change phone number on Twitter

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to change my phone number on Twitter but cannot find any link or button to get this from. I tried from phone and from desktop also.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update it from More =>  Settings => Your Account => Account Information => Phone from [Twitter Web](https://twitter.com/settings/phone)

Comment: solved, thanks a lot